# Take multiple pictures per second with Logitech webcam 600

Tags: webcam

I have a Logitech webcam 600. I use the software that installs by default(Logitech Webcam Software) in Windows 7 when I plugin the camera. I would like to take multiple pictures per second(the most that is possible). I would like to do this a set ammount of time to save the pictures. Basicaly like making a video, just that I save each frame separetely. Can I do this, what software do I need to download?

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need images to start with, or can you take an intermediate step? I wonder if the CCD in the can take them fast enough for your liking, most webcams arent usually exactly made to take rapid shots like that.

One idea is to record video, then convert the video to stills. Similar to how you can break apart a .gif image into its single frames.

Comment: I was thinking about this, do you know any good software to convert video to frames.

Comment: Not really, but I know someone who does... https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+video+to+frames